# Prisma prisma.artworks.findMany() Unknown argument `tags`. Available options are marked with?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm trying to filter artwork objects based on multiple fields, one of which is the tag name. However, it failed.

My data structure:

```
model artworks {
  id            String          @id @default(dbgenerated("uuid_generate_v4()")) @db.Uuid
  title         String          @db.VarChar(255)
  artistid      String          @db.Uuid
  description   String?
  dataadded     DateTime?       @default(now()) @db.Time(6)
  isavailable   Boolean?        @default(true)
  imageurl      String          @db.VarChar(500)
  artworkimages artworkimages[]
  users         users           @relation(fields: [artistid], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "fk_artistid")
  artworktags   artworktags[]
  comments      comments[]
  likes         likes[]
  products      products[]
}

model artworktags {
  artworkid String   @db.Uuid
  tagid     String   @db.Uuid
  artworks  artworks @relation(fields: [artworkid], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  tags      tags     @relation(fields: [tagid], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)

  @@id([artworkid, tagid])
}

model tags {
  id          String        @id @default(dbgenerated("uuid_generate_v4()")) @db.Uuid
  name        String        @db.VarChar(20)
  description String?       @db.VarChar(500)
  color       String?       @db.VarChar(20)
  createddate DateTime?     @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(6)
  isactive    Boolean?      @default(true)
  artworktags artworktags[]
  producttags producttags[]
}
```

Here is the `getArtworks()` method:

```
export async function getArtworks(
  page: number, 
  pageSize: number, 
  availability: boolean | null = null, 
  searchTerm?: string
): Promise<ArtworkWithImagesTagsAndArtist[]> {
  try {
    const included = availability === null ? {} : { isavailable: availability };
    const searchFilter = searchTerm 
      ? {
          OR: [
            { title: { contains: searchTerm } },
            { description: { contains: searchTerm } },
            { users: { name: { contains: searchTerm } } },
            { artworktags: { tags: { name: { contains: searchTerm } } } },
            { artworkimages: { name: { contains: searchTerm } } },
          ],
        } 
      : {};
    const combinedFilter: any | undefined = { ...included, ...searchFilter };
    const artworks = await prisma.artworks.findMany({
      skip: (page - 1) * pageSize,
      take: pageSize,
      include: {
        artworkimages: true,
        artworktags: {
          include: {
            tags: true
          }
        },
        users: true
      },
      where: combinedFilter,
    });
    return artworks;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch artworks:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch artworks.');
  }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Failed to fetch artworks: PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.artworks.findMany()` invocation:

{
  skip: 0,
  take: 10,
  include: {
    artworkimages: true,
    artworktags: {
      include: {
        tags: true
      }
    },
    users: true
  },
  where: {
    OR: [
      {
        title: {
          contains: "test"
        }
      },
      {
        description: {
          contains: "test"
        }
      },
      {
        users: {
          name: {
            contains: "test"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        artworktags: {
          tags: {
            name: {
              contains: "test"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        artworkimages: {
          name: {
            contains: "test"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Unknown argument `tags`. Available options are marked with ?.
    at ti (G:\Work\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:118:5888)
    at si.handleRequestError (G:\Work\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:125:6473)
    at si.handleAndLogRequestError (G:\Work\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:125:6151)
    at si.request (G:\Work\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:125:5859)
    at async l (G:\Work\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:130:10025)
    at async getArtworks (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./src/lib/actions.ts:152:26)
    at async G:\Work\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:406
    at async t0 (g:\Work\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:5773)
    at async rh (g:\Work\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:23636)
    at async doRender (g:\Work\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1391:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (g:\Work\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1552:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (g:\Work\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1460:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (g:\Work\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1843:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (g:\Work\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1881:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (g:\Work\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:909:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (g:\Work\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:266:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (G:\Work\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:805:17) {name: 'PrismaClientValidationError', clientVersion: '5.7.1', stack: 'PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma…dules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:805:17)', message: '
Invalid `prisma.artworks.findMany()` invoca…`tags`. Available options are marked with ?.'}
```

---

Update:

Thanks to #37307554

I now updated my query to below and it works~!

{ artworkimages: { some:{ name: { contains: searchTerm, mode: 'insensitive' } } } },
{ artworktags: { some: { tags: { name: { contains: searchTerm, mode: 'insensitive' } } } } },